# Why my javascript won't post or submit to my database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp-classic

I've create a form using `jQuery` and I want to submit it into my `SQL SERVER` Database by `AJAX`. but It won't submit, I don't know where the problems comes. I create this site with ASP.

Here is the `javascript` to submit:

```
$("#reg_tr_new").click(function(){
    $("#refresh_tr").submit();
});

$("#refresh_tr").validate({
    debug: false,
    rules:  {
                deskripsi: "required"
            },
    messages:   { 
                    deskripsi: {
                        required: 'Deskripsi harus diisi'
                    }
                },
    success: "valid",
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $("#right-container").hide();
        $("#add_no").show();
        .post('trx_menu/queries/svTR_.asp', $("#refresh_tr").serialize(), function(data) {
            $('#refresh_tr_show').html(data);
        });
    }
});
```

Here is the code in `trx_menu/queries/svTR_.asp`:

```
<%
noTrx=request.form("noTrx")
deskripsi=request.form("deskripsi")
from=request.form("from")
tos=request.form("tos")
user_input=Session("ss_ckduser")
BankTrx=request.form("BankTrx")
Dim tgl_inpt
tgl_inpt=Now

strsql="select count(*)+1 as idtrbaru from "& dbweb &".dbo.trmitrareghd"
set qdata = conn.execute(strsql)
idbaru = qdata("idtrbaru")

strsql="insert into "& dbweb &".dbo.trmitrareghd  values('"& idbaru &"','"& noTrx &"','"&BankTrx&"','"& deskripsi &"','"&date()&"','"&date()&"','0','"&  user_input &"','"& tgl_inpt &"')"
set qdata = conn.execute(strsql)
'response.write strsql
%>
```

Comment: Do you have Firefox and/or Firebug available? You might want to check what server code you get back from the post.

Comment: Check a network panel on chrome.press f12 for shortcut and know a process of sending and returning of ajax page.

Comment: @TiesonT. I've got this message on my firebug `POST svTR_.asp 500 Internal Server Error`

Comment: @devtut okay, I will try, but I need to install chrome first :)

Comment: no need to install chrome if you already have firebug just to debug this. Firebug site has info on how to look at console

Comment: @blankon91 Okay, you should see a little plus button next to the post log (assuming you're looking in the console tab). Expand that, and then look at what is in the HTML tab. It should show you the error page with stack trace, etc.

Comment: @TiesonT. Okay, I get it, I have problem in my datetime format :) thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have the validation plugin `debug` option set to true which blocks form submittal while you ...debug!

You are also missing a `$` before `post`

```
 .post('trx_menu/queries/svTR_.asp'......
```

Should be:

```
$.post('trx_menu/queries/svTR_.asp'......
```

Use a browser console to check script and syntax errors as well as to inspect the request itself.

Comment: what didn't work?  What errors are thrown? WHat is request status . Can't troubleshoot without details

Comment: I've got this `The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.`

Comment: that's not a script error, either a plugin debug log, or coming from server. Did it show as "error"

Comment: kill the validator first, you have way too many things going on that you aren't familiar with. Get the ajax working, then sort out validator

Comment: @chaelifl Okay, I get it, I have problem in my datetime format :) thanks